# Django :: Reference foreign key

Tags: python, django, one-to-many

I want to create a page where I can display properties by their pictures on a webpage.

Currently, My Property model looks like this (some codes are taken out):

```
class Property(models.Model):
    PROPERTY_TYPE = (('Room', 'Room'), ('House', 'House'))
    type = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=PROPERTY_TYPE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True)
    beds = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    payment_term = models.CharField(choices=PAYMENT_TERM_CHOICES, max_length=50)
```

and Picture model

```
class Picture(models.Model):
    location = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    alt = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    parent_property = models.ForeignKey(Property, null=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

In my view, I get the list of objects like this:

```
room_list = Property.objects.all().filter(type='Room').order_by('timestamp')[6]
```

When running a for loop through the passed room_list list, I want to reference it like

Room's list of picture's first image

I tried going through Django's official documentation on One to Many relationships but I cannot seem to follow it.

How would I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you can use something like this:

```
{% for room in room_list %}
   <img src="{{ room.picture_set.first }}"/>
{% endfor %}
```

I don't recommend it. The reason is, that for every room_list item, you go to the database for Picture item. So when you have 30 items for example, you will bombard database with 31 queries.

The easiest thing you can do, is to add another field for you Property model, say default_picture, that will be FK to the Picture with None as default. After you save Picture, you fill the ID of that Picture (which Picture you use and how do you handle records without Picture is on your business logic). Then you get the records this way:

```
room_list = Property.objects.filter(
    type='Room'
).select_related(
    'default_picture'
).order_by('timestamp')[6]
```

This will result in a single query. Sure there are another methods to achieve the same but these are more complicated.

TIP: you don't need to order by timestamp field (unless you modify its value), but you can use ID as it is created in sequence. This is cheaper operation (at least in Postgres).

Update:
As @JamesLin suggested, you could use something like this:

```
room_list = Property.objects.filter(
    type='Room'
).prefetch_related(
    'picture_set'
)
```

This will be translated into two queries, one for the Property list and the second one for all Picture records related to pulled Property items (Django will connect them programmatically). This is quite a lazy for the programmer but consider that you are loading all Picture records per Property. But this is certainly a better solution than the picture_set and easier to implement than my first suggestion (it doesn't automatically mean that better solution).

Comment: I tried using this solution by adding default_pic = models.ForeignKey(Picture) and somehow schemamigration gave me an error saying it cannot find Picture

Comment: You can just add select_related() without adding the extra field because you are very likely to paginate your result to around 10 records, let's say you have 5 photos for each house, you are going to get 50 rows including photos, so there is virtually not much performance difference.

Comment: It is not a problem of migrations. You are trying to access Picture class but at that point, it was not yet defined (it is defined later in the code). Just pass the class name as string and Django will do the rest.

Comment: @James Lin I would not bet at this. Yes, you can have pagination with small number of items, but someday somebody decides that why only 10 items, change it to 50... and service is down. It is definitely not a good practice.

Comment: I seriously doubt that having 250 records will bring the service down unless you are running this on a raspberry pi, having a `default_picture` in the house model, instead of photo is dependent on house, now house needs to know about photo model, this also means the default_photo field has to be nullable, plus, a house can now have a default photo from another set of house photos.

Comment: Correction to my comment, `select_related()` only works on foreignkey/one-to-one relationship, so my first comment suggested using `select_related` alone without the extra field suggested by @bruce won't give any optimization. Use `prefetch_related()` instead

Comment: @JamesLin I wouldn't go into deeper discussion about this topics, because it depends on many factors but in principle it is a performance killer, so it should be used wisely. Yes, prefetch_related can be used too, but again, this loads all the related Picture records even he needs to load only one. Unless there are not many Picture records per Property, this could be better solution than the picture_set. At least from the lazy point of view ;)

Answer (score 0):

`room_list.picture_set.all()` is how you can access the picture set. To get the first one, you could just access `room_list.picture_set.first()`. Template version: `{{ room_list.picture_set.first }}`.

[Relevant Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/relations/).

[.first documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#first)

Comment: Where does room_list and picture_set come from? Are they automatically generated variables?

Comment: room_list is the variable you mentioned from the view. Its name doesn't really matter, as long as you add it to the request that is sent to the template. picture_set is generated automatically (follow the link in my answer).

Answer (score 0):

Simply answering your question here:

```
{% for room in room_list %}
   <img src="{{ room.picture_set.first }}"/>
{% endfor %}
```

Then there is a whole [chapter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/optimization/) to optimize it.

BTW:

This query will only give you the 7th house

```
room_list = Property.objects.all().filter(type='Room').order_by('timestamp')[6]
```

you probably want `[:6]`

Also you don't need to call `.all()` before `.filter()`

```
room_list = Property.objects.filter(type='Room').order_by('timestamp')[:6]
```